# The jquery selector always selecting even it should not

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

```
$("#question-proper table tr td input[value='Save']").on('click',function(){
        var number = parseInt($(this).attr('data'));
        $(this).attr("value","Add");
        alert("Clicked");
});
```

When i click again  the input button with the value of Add. It alerts again as not expected. It should not because the value now  of input button is "Add" not the "Save".

Comment: You have already attached the click handler to that element, and it _stays_ attached as long as you don’t remove it. This has nothing to do with whether the selector used to reference the element matches any more or not.

Comment: If you want this to be dynamic, use event delegation.

Comment: @CBroe ahmm..thank you. :D can you please show me? i take 3 hours trouble shooting this. I owe you.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on("click", "input[value='Save']", function(){
    $(this).attr("value", "Add");
    alert("clicked");
});
```

adapt this to fit your needs

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/omofa2v9/

Read about event delegation [**here**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 0):

The event is bound to the element and is kept even if it no longer match the query. In fact, the event don't even know what the query was, only the actual elements it was added to.

Possible solutions:

Delegate to a parent element:

```
$("#question-proper table tr td").on('click', "input[value='Save']", function(){        
    var number = parseInt($(this).attr('data'));
    $(this).attr("value","Add");
    alert("Clicked");
});
```

Check in the event:

```
$("#question-proper table tr td input[value='Save']").on('click',function(){
    if($this).attr('value') !== 'Save') return;

    var number = parseInt($(this).attr('data'));
    $(this).attr("value","Add");
    alert("Clicked");
});
```

Run the event only once by using `.one`:

```
$("#question-proper table tr td input[value='Save']").one('click',function(){
    var number = parseInt($(this).attr('data'));
    $(this).attr("value","Add");
    alert("Clicked");
});
```

Comment: Note: The past tense of "bind" is "bound" (not binded).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Thanks, fixed. In these small typos, you can just edit the answer directly.